# Finding and changing tuples values

Tags: java, arraylist, tuples

I have some tuples already made like so:

```
public GreenhouseControls() {
        light = new Tuple<>("light", "off");
        fans = new Tuple<>("fans", "off");
        water = new Tuple<>("water", "off");
        power = new Tuple<>("power", "on");
        window = new Tuple<>("window", "good");
        thermostat = new Tuple<>("thermostat","day");
}
```

and I'm trying to use a `setVariable()` method in the same class that will take in 2 string (for example, "light" and "on") and would use the first string to search the first variable of the tuple and when a match is found it would replace the second variable with the second string.
I tried adding the tuples to an ArrayList but I can't get the search part to work.
Is there a way to achieve this maybe with either an `ArrayList` or a `HashSet`?

---

Tuple class:

```
   public static class Tuple<A,B> {
        public final A eventName;
        public final B status;

        public Tuple(A eventName, B status) {
            this.eventName = eventName;
            this.status = status;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + eventName + ", " + status + ")";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is more suitable?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm not really familiar with HashMap (but I googled so I think I got the basics of it) so you mean storing the tuples in the hashmap or using a hashmap instead of the tuples?

Comment: Why use a hashmap? Or any list data structure for that matter? I'd read up on Java object orientation and use common patterns, getter/setter methods to achieve this?

Comment: are you using `groovy.lang.Tuple`?

Comment: @Jesse but even if I use a getter/setter inside the getter I'll need a way to check each tuple for the string I'm looking for so I'll need a way to look at each tuple and that would require a list or a hashmap right?

Comment: @Shyam no I have a Tuple class in my code I'm not importing it I just added it to my post

Comment: Then, a `HashMap` will be a better match for your problem

Comment: @Shayam yeah but if can't replace the tuples with a HashSet (it's part of an assignment and they like making everything a pain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to create relationships between keys and values. In your case, a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) would be appropriate and would make your code much more concise and easy to read. You can use [`put(key,value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) to set the value of a key and use [`get(key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-) to retrieve the value associated with a key.

```
final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("light","off");
//Etc..

//Get value
String light = map.get("light");//"off"
//Update value
map.put("light","on");
light = map.get("light");//"on"
```

If you are not allowed to change the structure of your code, you can implement it with your `Tuple` class using foreach loops like so:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class GreenhouseControls {    
    private final List<Tuple<String,String>> members;
    public GreenhouseControls() {
        members = Arrays.asList(
                new Tuple<>("light", "off"),
                new Tuple<>("fans", "off"),
                new Tuple<>("water", "off"),
                new Tuple<>("power", "on"),
                new Tuple<>("window", "good"),
                new Tuple<>("thermostat","day")
               );
    }
    
    public void setVariable(final String eventName, final String status) {
        for(final Tuple<String, String> tuple: members) {
            if(tuple.getEventName().equals(eventName)) {
                tuple.setStatus(status);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No event found with eventName " + eventName);
    }
    
    public String getVariable(final String eventName) {
        for(final Tuple<String, String> tuple: members) {
            if(tuple.getEventName().equals(eventName)) {
                return tuple.getStatus();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public static class Tuple<A, B> {
        private A eventName;
        private B status;

        public Tuple(final A eventName, final B status) {
            this.eventName = eventName;
            this.status = status;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + eventName + ", " + status + ")";
        }

        public B getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(B status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public A getEventName() {
            return eventName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks good and it would honestly make my life easier but I'm afraid that since this is all part of an assignment I have to use tuples is unavoidable would there be a way to do the same thing but with tuples?

Comment: i'm trying to print the array that the tuples are stored in but it just looks emty like if the print statment isn't working. Shouldn't `System.out.println(members)` work ?

Comment: @dxbh0517 Do you have any other questions or concerns?

Comment: nope I found what I was doing wrong thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented how you could do this for a single variable of an object. i.e. "Light".
Is there a reason why you need to have a redundant variable captured as a tuple?

```
public class GreenhouseControls {
  
    private String light;
    
    public String getLightStatus() {
        return light;
    }
   
   public void setLightStatus(String input)
   {
       if(input == "on" || input == "off")
       this.light = input;
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       GreenhouseControls controls = new GreenhouseControls();
       controls.setLightStatus("on");
       System.out.println(controls.getLightStatus());
       controls.setLightStatus("off");
       System.out.println(controls.getLightStatus());
   }
   
}
```

Comment: `input == "on" || input == "off"` may lead to a bug,

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use `HashMap` for your requirement as suggested by hev1. But if you still want to make use of the `Tuple` class, then here is one way of doing it.

Add getter methods to your `Tuple` class

```
public class Tuple<A,B> {
    public final A eventName;
    public final B status;

    public Tuple(A eventName, B status) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + eventName + ", " + status + ")";
    }

    public A getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public B getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Then collect all your tuples in a `List` and pass it to your `setVariable` method. Within this method just check if the given `eventName` is present in any of the tuples. If yes, then remove that Tuple from the list and create a new Tuple with the given status and add it back to the list. Something like this:

```
void setVariable(String eventName, String status, List<Tuple>tuples) {
    boolean isRemoved = tuples.removeIf(tuple -> tuple.getEventName().equals(eventName));
    if(isRemoved) {
        Tuple tuple = new Tuple(eventName, status);
        tuples.add(tuple);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't tried your answer yet but I think it will work but wouldn't be easier I guess not have `List<Tuple>tuples` as an input for `setVariable` since there will be only one list if I declare it in the class i would be able to use it inside `setVariable`. or would that not work?

Comment: @dxbh0517 Yes. If you wish to use a single list at class level, then there is no need to pass it to the `setVariable` method. As the method has access to the list